# angular google map redraw upon resizing

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am using Angular Google Maps 
[Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) for one of my project.

The problem i am facing is how to redraw the angular google maps upon resizing the browser / tilt the orientation of the mobile device screen so that the location marker appears on the center of the map after resizing the browser. (in angular js way)

Answer (score -1):

You need to decide what events you want to have resize this, maybe it's window resize but you'd do something like this

```
 MyResizeFunction(){
    $timeout(function(){
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    },100);
};
```

Where MyResizeFunction is whatever event you want to call the resize, and map is your map object,